# How to open link in new tab in php

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have one array.It is created in config file.When i make a click on **Employee Summary** this link will be open in next tab.Plz suggest how can i do this?

```
"Employee Summary" => array(
                "title" => "Employee Summary",
                "url" => APP_URL.'/report_own.php'
)
```

Comment: add `target = '_blank'` into your array

Comment: It would help if you were more specific on how this array gets turned into <anchors> otherwise no one will be able to give you an answer which works.

Comment: Or if you're using some framework that does this you'll need to specify.

Comment: A PHP array cannot open links. There's quite a bit missing between here and there. This is unanswerable as is.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Target-HTML-Tag.

```
<a href="YOUR_URL" target="_blank">Title</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set Target= "Blank" To open in new tab..

```
<a target = '_blank' href='view_detail.php?nevna=$Sid_v' >$check</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
"Employee Summary" => array(
            "title" => "Employee Summary",
            "url" => APP_URL.'/report_own.php',
            "target" => '_blank'
)
```

Comment: i had try this but its not working

Comment: Then try this "Employee Summary" => array(
            "title" => "Employee Summary",
            "url" => APP_URL.'/report_own.php'
),array('target' => '_blank')

Answer (score -2):

It seems that in the following array, keys are the HTML attributes and values are the attribute values.

So, there is an attribute `target` if we set it to `_blank`, after clicking on the link, the link opens in a new tab/window depending upon environment.

```
"Employee Summary" => array(
  "title" => "Employee Summary",
  "url" => APP_URL.'/report_own.php',
  'target' => '_blank'

)
```

Comment: i had already try this but its not working.. is there any other option available?